# How to get nested href in python?

Tags: python, html, href

### GOAL

(I need to repeatedly do the search for hundreds of times):

**1.** Search (e.g. "WP_000177210.1") in "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ipg/"

(i.e. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ipg/?term=WP_000177210.1)

**2.** Select the first record in the second column "CDS Region in Nucleotide" of the table

(i.e. " NC_011415.1 1997353-1998831 (-)", https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_011415.1?from=1997353&to=1998831&strand=2)

**3.** Select "FASTA" under the name of this sequence

**4.** Get the fasta sequence

(i.e. ">NC_011415.1:c1998831-1997353 Escherichia coli SE11, complete sequence
ATGACTTTATGGATTAACGGTGACTGGATAACGGGCCAGGGCGCATCGCGTGTGAAGCGTAATCCGGTAT
CGGGCGAG.....").

## CODE

**1.** Search (e.g. "WP_000177210.1") in "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ipg/"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ipg/"
r = requests.get(url, params = "WP_000177210.1")
if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
```

**2.** Select the first record in the second column "CDS Region in Nucleotide" of the table  (In this case "    NC_011415.1 1997353-1998831 (-)") (i.e. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_011415.1?from=1997353&to=1998831&strand=2)

```
# try 1 (wrong)
## I tried this first, but it seemed like it only accessed to the first level of the href?!
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if (a['href'][:8]) =="/nuccore":
        print("Found the URL:", a['href'])

# try 2 (not sure how to access nested href)
## According to the label I saw in the Develop Tools, I think I need to get the href in the following nested structure. However, it didn't work.
soup.select("html div #maincontent div div div #ph-ipg div table tbody tr td a")
```

I am stuck in this step right now....

## PS

It's my first time to deal with html format. It's also my first time to ask question here. I might not phrase the problem very well. If there's anything wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using NCBI's REST API,

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Opens a firefox webbrowser for scrapping purposes
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'your\path\geckodriver.exe') # Put your own path here

# Allows you to load a page completely (with all of the JS)
browser.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ipg/?term=WP_000177210.1')

# Delay turning the page into a soup in order to collect the newly fetched data
time.sleep(3)

# Creates the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html")

# Gets all the links by filtering out ones with just '/nuccore' and keeping ones that include '/nuccore'
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if '/nuccore' in a['href'] and not a['href'] == '/nuccore']
```

#### Note:

> You'll need the package [`selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)
>
> You'll need to install [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)